# Errors with Flow, ReactJS and ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Why are these errors showing with `flow`. I'm using React with ES6 classes. Code example is below:

**UPDATE**

I almost got this working based on this example:
https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#defining-components-as-react-component-subclasses

I got rid of most of the Flow errors, but now app fails when run it. I think this is ReactJS not stripping out the Flow or Babel class stuff. If I comment out the Flow type defs in my code below I don't get this error.

I'm running my app with `watchify -t [ babelify ] app.js -o ./build/app.js`

> SyntaxError:
>   /Users/carlf/Documents/dev/reactjs/FlyTweet/app/views/posts/MyNewPostForm.js:
>   Missing class properties transform. while parsing file:
>   /Users/carlf/Documents/dev/reactjs/FlyTweet/app/views/posts/MyNewPostForm.js

Flow Errors:

> app/views/posts/MyNewPostForm.js:51  51:     var myPostTxt =
>   ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.Refs.content).value;
>                                                      ^^^^ property `Refs`. Property not found in  15: export default class MyNewPostForm
>   extends React.Component {
>                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ MyNewPostForm

From **package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babelify": "7.3.0",
    "react": "15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "15.1.0",
    "react-router": "2.4.1"
  }
```

**React Component**

```
export default class MyNewPostForm extends React.Component {

  // START Flow type definitions.
  MAX_POST_CHARS: number; 

  state: {
      charsRemaining: number,
      SendButtonDisabled: boolean
  };

  handleChange: () => void;
  onSubmit: () => void;
  // END Flow type definitions.

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.MAX_POST_CHARS = 139;

    this.state = {
        charsRemaining: this.MAX_POST_CHARS,
        SendButtonDisabled: true
    };

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);    
   this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);    

  }

  handleChange() {
     var myPostTxt = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.content).value;

     // Do something here.
  }
```

Comment: When creating a component using flow, you have to provide type parameters in your class declaration to describe the types of your props, default props, and state. [Here's a useful article](http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/type-checking-react-with-flow.html)

Comment: I was following the official Flow / React ES6 example here and couldn't get this working either: http://flowtype.org/docs/react.html#defining-components-as-react-component-subclasses

Comment: Also what kinda irks me is with non-React running flow on a JS file won't show any errors until AFTER you add type annotations. But with React ES6 it's forcing me to add type annotations.

Answer (score 1):

May be the only flow error is capital R in `Refs`?
It is in lower case in code you provided, but in the error message it is capital.

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer. [Flow knows that `React.Component` classes have a `ref` property](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/6cc92ca6d561964f05dc04585300422c2836e9df/lib/react.js#L43) and class properties are case sensitive